# How to increase the accuracy of EigenFaceRecognizer, it recognizes two people as one?

Tags: c++, opencv, face-recognition, eigenvector

I'm trying to recognize frontal faces using EigenFaceRecognizer in C++.

The problem is:

1) at high threshold, two people are recognized as same person and a "NEW" face is also recognized, instead of stating it as a new face

2) at low thresholds, a face already in the training set is recognized as a new face

3) False Positives are also encountered. Though not a concern but if an easy way is suggested to decrease them it will be appreciated>

Is there any way to improve the recognizer to identify faces accurately?

Following is what I am doing.

```
 #include<opencv2\opencv.hpp>                //For opencv functions
#include<opencv2\highgui\highgui.hpp>       //For window based functions
#include<fstream>                           //For dealing with I/O operations on file

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;


// Function to read the File containing paths and labels of the training images and push them into images and     labels vector
static void read_data(vector <Mat> & images,vector <int>& labels, char separator=' ')
{
ifstream file("images.txt");   //images.txt contains paths and labels separated by a space
string line;
string a[2];

 while(getline(file,line))  // read images.txt line by line 
 {
     int i=0;
stringstream iss(line);
while (iss.good() && i < 2)
{
    iss>>a[i]; 
    ++i;
}
images.push_back(imread(a[0],CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE)); // a[0] = "path of images"
labels.push_back(atoi(a[1].c_str()));  //a[1] = "labels"
}

file.close();
  }


  // Function to take input from webcam and recognize faces 
   int face_recognition::face_rec(int time_flag, int trigger_flag)
  {

 vector<Mat> images;    //stores the paths of all images
vector<int> labels;    //stores the corresponding labels

//function call to function read_data
read_data(images,labels);    

//take the size of the sample images
int im_width = images[0].cols;           
int im_height = images[0].rows;

//threshold is the minimum value of magnitude of vector of EigenFaces
double threshold=10.0;    

//create instance of EigenFaceRecognizer
Ptr<FaceRecognizer> model = createEigenFaceRecognizer(10,threshold);  
double current_threshold =model->getDouble("threshold");

// set a threshold value, for face prediction
model->set("threshold",5000.0);      

// train the face recognizer using the sample images
model->train(images,labels);         

// Create face_cascade to detect people
CascadeClassifier face_cascade;
if(!face_cascade.load("haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml"))   // load     haarcascade_frontaface_default.xml
{ 
cout<<"ERROR Loading cascade file";
return 1;
}

// capture the video input from webcam
VideoCapture capture(CV_CAP_ANY);    

capture.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 320);
capture.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 240); 

Size frameSize(static_cast<int>(320), static_cast<int>(240));

//initialize the VideoWriter object
VideoWriter oVideoWriter ("MyVideo.avi", CV_FOURCC('P','I','M','1'), 20, frameSize, true);  // video is save in the  VS  project

if(!capture.isOpened())
{
    cout<<"Error in camera";
return 1;
}

Mat cap_img, gray_img;

//store the detected faces
vector<Rect> faces;   
while(1)
{
//capture frame by frame in cap_img
capture>>cap_img;   
waitKey(10);


// Image conversion: Color to Gray
cvtColor(cap_img,gray_img,CV_BGR2GRAY);   

//Histogram Equilization to increase contrast by stretching intensity ranges
equalizeHist(gray_img,gray_img);      




// detects faces in the frame
//CV_HAAR_SCALE_IMAGE to scale the size of the detect face 
//CV_HAAR_DO_CANNY_PRUNING to increase speed as it skips image regions that are unlikely to contain a face
face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray_img,faces,1.1,10,CV_HAAR_SCALE_IMAGE | CV_HAAR_DO_CANNY_PRUNING, Size(20,20),Size(300,300));  

Mat Normalized;

//Loop over the detected faces
for(int i=0;i<faces.size();i++)
{
    Rect face_i = faces[i];
    Mat face = gray_img(face_i);

    Mat face_resized;

    //resize the detected face to the size of sample images
    resize(face,face_resized, Size(im_width,im_height),1.0,1.0,INTER_CUBIC);  


    // predict the person the face belongs to, returns label
    int predicted_label = -1;
    predicted_label=model->predict(face_resized); 

    // Draws a rectangle around the faces
    rectangle(cap_img,face_i, CV_RGB(0,255,0),1);   

    //text to be put with the face, by default "new" for new faces
    string box_text=format("new");  

    // Change the text based on label
    if(predicted_label>-1)
        switch(predicted_label)
        {
            case 0:box_text = format("keanu");
                   break;
            case 1:box_text = format("selena");
                   break;
            case 2:box_text = format("shubham");
                   break;
        }


    // calculate the coordinates to put the text based on the postion of the face 
    int pos_x = max(face_i.tl().x - 10, 0);
    int pos_y = max(face_i.tl().y - 10, 0);

    // put text on the output screen
    putText(cap_img, box_text , Point(pos_x,pos_y), FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN,0.8, CV_RGB(0,255,0), 1,CV_AA);  

    if (box_text=="new")
    {
       oVideoWriter.write(cap_img); //writer the frame into the file
    }
}

// show the frame on the result window
imshow("Press Esc to exit",cap_img); 

if(waitKey(30)==27)         
    break; 
}
```

return 0;
}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem. The answer ([and code](https://github.com/MasteringOpenCV/code/tree/master/Chapter8_FaceRecognition)) is in Chapter 8 of the [Mastering OpenCV](https://www.packtpub.com/application-development/mastering-opencv-practical-computer-vision-projects) book by the awesome Shervin Emami. [Here's his blog post](http://www.shervinemami.info/faceRecognition.html) on the subject.

Mainly you need to do some pre-processing on the face which includes the following steps

1. When training, do a diff between consecutive frames and only pre-process the frame if it is noticeably different from the previous one
2. Add both the image and a mirrored version to the training set so that you have more training data, also to deal with faces that are looking to the left or right
3. Histogram equalisation to improve the contrast and brightness of a face
4. The face is scaled, rotated, translated so that the eyes are aligned.
5. Removal of forehead, chin, ears, and background from the face image
6. Separate histogram equalisation for left and right sides of the face independently
7. Smoothing or removing noise using a bilateral filter
8. Elliptical mask to remove remaining hair and background

Cheers.